# Given adjacency rules and unsorted array, return array conforming to rules

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, sorting, constraints

Let's say I have an array of some characters and a set of rules:

```
char[] chars = new int[]{ 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H' }; 
char[][] rules = { {'A', 'B'} , {'C', 'B'}, {'F', 'E'} }
```

The characters in `chars` are distinct, and `rules` is a 2D array of pairs of characters which must be beside each other in the output.

I want to return an array containing all elements of `chars` that satisfies all of the constraints in `rules`. The array should be alphabetically earliest if there are multiple possible options. There is guaranteed to be at least one solution.

How would I go about approaching this problem? I'm not quite sure how to start.

Comment: this looks like topological sorting can be used here. you should study that : https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/topological-sorting/

Comment: It's not topological sorting. Topological sorting does not impose any constraints about adjacency in the output, just relative order.

Comment: Are the characters in `chars` necessarily distinct? Are the rules guaranteed to be consistent, i.e. is there always a solution?

Comment: @kaya3 Yes and yes: all elements of `chars` are distinct and a solution always exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the characters are distinct and each character can only appear next to two other characters in the output, each character must appear in at most two rules. If we consider the rules as edges in a [graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_(discrete_mathematics)), then they form a disjoint set of paths.

The earliest solution in alphabetical order can be formed by finding all of the characters which either aren't in any path, or are the endpoints of paths, and inserting them into the output in alphabetical order. When a path endpoint is inserted, we have to insert the rest of that path in order before continuing.

To conveniently find nodes with zero or one edges, and iterate along the paths, we'll start by converting the [edge list data structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edge_list) into an [adjacency list data structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_list).

```java
import java.util.*;

public class Solution {
    public static char[] solve(char[] letters, char[][] rules) {
        // convert to adjacency list
        Map<Character, List<Character>> neighbours = new HashMap<>();
        for(char[] edge : rules) {
            char a = edge[0], b = edge[1];
            neighbours.computeIfAbsent(a, ArrayList::new).add(b);
            neighbours.computeIfAbsent(b, ArrayList::new).add(a);
        }

        // find nodes with 0 or 1 edges, in order
        List<Character> endpoints = new ArrayList<>();
        for(char a : letters) {
            if(!neighbours.containsKey(a) || neighbours.get(a).size() <= 1) {
                endpoints.add(a);
            }
        }
        Collections.sort(endpoints);

        // build output
        char[] out = new char[letters.length];
        Set<Character> used = new HashSet<>();
        int i = 0;
        for(char a : endpoints) {
            if(used.contains(a)) { continue; }
            out[i++] = a;
            used.add(a);
            // if it's a path, iterate along path
            while(neighbours.containsKey(a) && !neighbours.get(a).isEmpty()) {
                char b = neighbours.get(a).get(0);
                out[i++] = b;
                used.add(b);
                // remove previous neighbour so next one guaranteed at index 0
                neighbours.get(b).remove((Character) a); // don't convert to int
                a = b;
            }
        }
        return out;
    }
}
```

Example:

```java
>>> Solution.solve(
...     new char[] { 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H' },
...     new char[][] { {'A', 'B'} , {'D', 'B'}, {'G', 'E'}, {'H', 'A'} }
... )
... 
char[8] { 'C', 'D', 'B', 'A', 'H', 'E', 'G', 'F' }
```